# Open popup at the location of the button clicked

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to create a popup that opens similar to the window preview option in Windows 8 taskbar. Basically, when I click or hover on a button, it opens a popup with basic information just above the button. Here is an example.
[image: Windows 8 taskbar]

Right now, I am able to open the popup at either the extreme left or extreme right side of the page, using the code below.

```
<Frame x:Name="PopUpFrame" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Visibility="Hidden" Height="400" Margin="10,10,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="400" Source="/BasicApp;component/StandingOrderPopUp.xaml" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"/>
```

I have 3 different buttons in the button bar, so I cannot set the fixed margin. I am trying to set the same in code but I am unable to get the absolute position and convert it to margin property. I am not sure, if there is a better solution either.

Edit:

Tried using popup but it doesn't open on button click.

```
        <Popup x:Name="PopUpFrame" Placement="Top" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=StandingOrderButton}" Width="400" Height="400">
        <DockPanel Background="#770081a7">
            <Canvas DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" x:Name="PopupButtonBar" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                <Button Height="30" Width="125" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Canvas.Top="10" Content="CLOSE" Foreground="White" Background="#ff0081a7" BorderBrush="White" FontFamily="Trebuchet MS" Canvas.Left="10" />
            </Canvas>
            <Label Margin="5,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Content="STANDING ORDERS" Foreground="#ffffffff"></Label>
            <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="#FFff7a00"></Border>
                <RichTextBox Margin="2" Foreground="#FF0081a7" FontFamily="Trebuchet MS" IsEnabled="False"/>
            </Grid>
        </DockPanel>
    </Popup>
```

And here is the event handler.

```
    Private Sub StandingOrder_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    PopUpFrame.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Visible
End Sub
```

Edit:

Never mind. I am an idiot. Instead of setting IsOpen property, I set the visibility. :(

It works perfectly, although, I had to copy the whole design from the separate page to this one. Still better than nothing. Only problem now is if I click on something else, I will have to write code to make sure popup is closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `Popup` control, coupled with it's `Placement` property to display your popup based on the current location of your buttons.

```
<Popup Placement="Top" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=yourButton}" ... />
```

Inside your `Popup`, you can place your `UserControl` or any content element which will act as the popup's content.

See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613596(v=vs.110).aspx) for further information on popup placements, and [here](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/WPFPopup.aspx) for a tutorial on WPF Popup controls.

Comment: I have to create a page for the display. Can I use popup control to display a WPF page? If yes, I think that might be the best bet here.

Answer (score 0):

Think about using ContextMenu, and set it's content you whatever you want. Thats is the solution for you.

Comment: ContextMenu will open on right click, yes? Can I open it on normal button click?

Comment: On click - context menu . open. or something like that, im pretty sure theres an option for selection the opening method

Answer (score 0):

This is how i defined one of my popups:

```
<Popup x:Name="btnPowerPopup" Placement="Mouse" StaysOpen="False">
....
</Popup>
```

you can user from the code behind on a button click or something :

```
btnPowerPopup.IsOpen = true;
```

and when the job is done:

```
btnPowerPopup.IsOpen = false;
```

But `StaysOpen="False"` let's you close the PopUp when clicking somewhere else.